# Java - Pointer to integer type

Tags: java, pointers

I want to have a pointer to an Integer type, **without making a custom class** that has an element which is an integer.

My desired effect:

```
Byte x = 5;         // Byte is just an example and WILL NOT work.
Byte y = x;
y--;
System.out.println(x + "," + y);
```

In which I want to print:

```
4,4
```

I thought `Byte`, `Integer`, or `Double` might be able to do this because they are sort of classes with an inner variable which is a primitive type but they don't keep references to the object that they are assigned to.

Comment: All of your proposed types *are* **immutable**. Try an `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: FYI: Java doesn't have *pointers*. In Java, they are called *references*.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think this is what I am looking for. I looked at the documentation and I see a lot of really strange methods. Decrement and get for example... so strange. How do I use this?

Comment: ... _why_ do you want to do this?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Essentially I have a `ArrayList` of `Integer`. One of the integers is very important and I need to keep track of it in case it drops to zero. The integer will be in the `ArrayList` but might be removed, moved around, etc from the `ArrayList` at any moment so I can't rely on using an index of the `ArrayList` to keep track of it. Values in the `ArrayList` will be changing all the time via another function so I need some way to have a reference to it, no matter where it is. Thus, I need some object type that stores integers that allows me to make references to it.

Comment: Uh, yeah, look; if you have a collection where one element is for some reason more important than the rest, you don't really have a unified collection.  What you're describing should **really** be solved some other way (by at minimum probably pulling the value out of the collection).  Posting another question with a bigger picture might yield some better insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a primitive wrapper type, because those are immutable. You could use an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) to do this. Something like,

```
AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger(5);
AtomicInteger y = x;
System.out.println(y.decrementAndGet() + "," + x.get());
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
4,4
```

**Or**, you could use an `int[]` like

```
int[] x = { 5 };
int[] y = x;
System.out.println(--x[0] + "," + y[0]);
```

for the same output.

Answer (score 1):

*I can't agree entirely with Elliott's answer about the `AtomicInteger` class. Not for those purposes it has been developed.*

I suggest you either

(1) considering [`commons-lang`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) classes (like [`MutableInt`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableDouble.html), [`MutableDouble`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableDouble.html)):

```
MutableInt wrapper = new MutableInt(value);
```

(2) wrapping a primitive type in a class-wrapper with corresponding `get`/`set` -ers:

```
class IntWrapper { private int value; }
```

(3) making an array of primitives:

```
int[] wrapper = new int[] { value };
```

Comment: Odd, when I try to type in MutableInt my Intellij doesn't automatically know the library of where it exists while pretty much any standard Java class, it would. Is this some external library? I see online it shows in the Java.lang from Apache but you'd think if it was in my JDK then Intellij would find it. Anyways, can you elaborate on the purposes of why `AtomicInteger` is developed? The more I read about it, the more I get confused on why it exists.

Comment: Commons-Lang is an Apache library. So, you would need to download it and include it in your classpath. It is a fairly-common third-party library, but a third-party library nonetheless and thus not a part of the standard JDK. Some people would frown on this answer based on that.

Comment: @Hatefiend, 1) you should download a `.jar` file from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4) and include it to your classpath.

Comment: With all due respect, it seems really extreme to use external libraries for something as simple as this, no?

Comment: @Hatefiend Manipulating a value to a primitive type through a reference is not simple in Java. Primitive types are not objects in Java. And while wrappers are, they are optimized for *common* use cases. Also, since you're using IntelliJ, you can add [commons-lang](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6#maven) to your pom.

Comment: @Hatefiend, 2) `AtomicInteger` has been developed for atomic operations in multithreading environments. Look over [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html).